# checkbox works only after second click after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create list of suppliers (checkboxes + labels) and search field to filter suppliers. I managed to get list renderered and after first load it works fine, but after I search through supplier list first click on checkbox doesn't work. I need to click twice for checkbox to become checked.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFwAX.jpg)

I need checkbox to become checked after first click when searching through supplier list. Please help.

I created this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nh7u4Lck/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="infoBlock suppliersWrapper">
        <div class="blockTitle">Supplier:</div>
        <div class="blockContent">
            <p class="checkedSupliersTitile">Supplier list:</p>
            <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8">                                 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control stickTop" placeholder="Search..." id="SearchSupplierInput">
                    <ul class="supplierList scrollable" id="suppliers"></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4">
                    <p class="checkedSupliersTitile">Checked suppliers:</p>
                    <p class="checkedSupliersText" id="checkedSuppliers">no suppliers selected</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.supplierList label {
    color: #575757;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.supplierList input[type="checkbox"   ]{
    width     : 2em;
    margin    : 0;
    padding   : 0;
    font-size : 1em;
    opacity   : 0;
}  

.supplierList input[type="checkbox"   ] + label{
    display      : inline-block;
    margin-left  : -1em;
    line-height  : 1.5em;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 33;
}

.supplierList input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 1px;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    left: -1.8em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.06em;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(25, 24, 25, 0.04) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(25, 24, 25, 0.04) inset;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(25, 24, 25, 0.04) inset;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.supplierList input[type="checkbox"   ]:checked + label:before{
    background:#46c87c;
}

.supplierList input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    color: #fff;
    content: "";
    font-family: "fontawesome";
    left: -1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SupplierList = [{"name":"125","id":"1"},
                    {"name":"2Bit Telecom Corporation","id":"2"},
                    {"name":"Alleven Telecom Corp Standart","id":"3"}];
var selectedSuppliers = [];
// Собираем и фильтруем активных поставшиков 


renderSupplierList(SupplierList);

$("#SearchSupplierInput").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var userInput = $(this).val();        
    var my_json = JSON.stringify(SupplierList);
    var filtered_supplierList = find_in_object(JSON.parse(my_json), {name:userInput});

    if (userInput.length >= 3) {
        $("#suppliers").html("");        
        renderSupplierList(filtered_supplierList);
    } else if(!userInput) {
        $("#suppliers").html("");
        renderSupplierList(SupplierList);
    }
});   

function renderSupplierList(array) {
    array.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if(typeof selectedSuppliers["id"+item.id] === 'undefined') {
        var ifCheckd = "";
    }
    else {
        var ifCheckd = "checked";
    }
    $("#suppliers").append('\
                <li><span>\n\
                <input class="supplierSelect" type="checkbox" id="supplier'+i+'" ' + ifCheckd + ' name="supplier" value="'+ item.id +'"> \n\
                <label for="supplier'+i+'">'+ item.name +'</label>\n\
                </span></li>');
    });       
}

function find_in_object(my_object, my_criteria) {

    return my_object.filter(function(obj) {
        //console.log(obj);
        return Object.keys(my_criteria).every(function(c) {
        //if (obj[c].search(/my_criteria[c]/i) == -1) {
            if (obj[c].search(new RegExp(my_criteria[c], "i")) == -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });

}

$('.supplierList').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    supplierCheckboxChange(this);
});

function sortSingle(array, key) {
    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    }

    function supplierCheckboxChange(currEl) {
        var cText = $( currEl ).siblings("label").text();
        var cID = "id" + currEl.value;

        if(currEl.checked) {
            selectedSuppliers[cID] = cText;
        }
        else {
            delete selectedSuppliers[cID];
        }

        var tmpSuppl = [];

        for (var key in selectedSuppliers) {
            tmpSuppl.push(selectedSuppliers[key]);
        }

        tmpSuppl.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a.toLowerCase(); var y = b.toLowerCase();
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });

        var suppliers = tmpSuppl.join(', ');
        if (!suppliers) {
            suppliers = "no suppliers selected";
        }

        $('#checkedSuppliers').text(suppliers);
    }  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `renderList` function  is being called more than once. First `keyup` is triggered when you press a key and then when text box looses focus(when you click on checkbox) `change` is triggered.

This causes your `renderList` method to get executed twice and the checked checkbox gets replace by a new checkbox.

To fix this, just change

```
$("#SearchSupplierInput").on("change paste keyup", function() { ... }
```

To

```
$("#SearchSupplierInput").on("paste keyup", function() { ... }
```

Have a look at this fiddle and check the console.  https://jsfiddle.net/nh7u4Lck/2/